# Value of SELECT is not refreshing JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created Self Invoking Function using Jquery where I'm creating some more select tags. But my main select tag's value is not being refershed.

Description :
I have select button which will have No_of_Children to select. When I select any value, say for example TWO then two more select tags (Child_Age) should be added in DOM.

The code is working very fine, it's creating two Tabs but the value of No_Of_Children is not being TWO it shows Zero Only.

```
(function () {
        var $RoomDesc = $("#RoomDesc");

        $RoomDesc.on("change", ".nights select", function () {
            console.log("a")
            // Check whether need to create Child Age or Destroy
            var $this = $(this);
            var values = parseInt($this.val());
            var childIDLength = ("CheckAvailability_RoomSearchCriteriaList_").length;
            var idValueOfTotalChildren = $this.attr('id').substr(childIDLength, 1);  // This is used to select perticular Room out of 4
            alert(idValueOfTotalChildren);


            var $currentChildAge = $("#room_" + idValueOfTotalChildren + " .childAge");
            var $noOfChildAge = $currentChildAge.children("select").length;
            var $noOfChildAgeCreate = values - $noOfChildAge;

            console.log("current " + $currentChildAge);
            console.log("no of child age " + $noOfChildAge);
            console.log("values : " + values);
            console.log("To create " + $noOfChildAgeCreate);

            if ($noOfChildAgeCreate <= 0) {
                for (var i = $noOfChildAge ; i > values ; i--) {
                    destroyChildAgeContainer(i, idValueOfTotalChildren);
                }
                // remove extra childAge
            } else {
                // create new childAge
                for (var i = ($noOfChildAge + 1) ; i <= (values) ; i++) {
                    // create tabs require new child's index no.
                    // be careful.
                    console.log("value if I : " + i);
                    console.log("value if idTotalChildren : " + i);
                    createChildAgeContainer(i, idValueOfTotalChildren);
                }
            }
        });
        return;
    })();
```

Comment: Please create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ that replicates the issue. Note that you have invalid selector at `var childIDLength`

Comment: It is a partial code so can't create fiddle, the value of child length is working perfect

Comment: Well there is nothing in code shown that would set any value so how are we supposed to help troubleshoot?